# Sum an array of milliseconds

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, time, reduce

I'm having an array of milliseconds which I want a total of. I have tried the array.reduce and use a for-loop but all I get is total gibberish when I console it or use on the site. If I get the milliseconds summed up I could convert them to seconds and, if needed, minutes.

Code:

```
window.timeArray = [2493, 2109, 4424, 1971, 3411, 1834, 2418]

let totalTimeSum = 0
for (let i = 0; i < window.timeArray.length; i++) {
  totalTimeSum += parseInt(window.timeArray[i])
}
document.querySelector('#score').innerText += totalTimeSum  
// 1866018660, should be 15249 - 15 sec 249 millisec
```

Optional code:

```
let totalTime = (sum, value) => sum + value
let totalTimeSum = window.timeArray.reduce(totalTime)
document.querySelector('#score').innerText += totalTimeSum  
// 1866018660, should be 15249 - 15 sec 249 millisec
```

Comment: why `parseInt` for numbers, `window` object and `+=` for `innerHTML`?

Comment: @NinaScholz I have a Div in which I want to add the time to, hence the += to InnerText. As for the other I got the ideas from the internet...

Comment: also, how do you end up at 15249? the sum of those numbers *is* 18660

Comment: @TimothyGroote I added them on the calculator, might have missed one number, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to accomplish what you need, you can do the following:

1. You can use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to calculate the sum of the array's elements.
2. Then, to calculate the number of seconds, round down the quotient of the `sum` divided by `1000`.
3. The remainder is the number of milliseconds remaining.

**Snippet:**

```js
var
  /* Define the array. */
  timeArray = [2493, 2109, 4424, 1971, 3411, 1834, 2418],
  
  /* Calculate the sum. */
  sum = timeArray.reduce((previous, current) => previous + current, 0),
  
  /* Calculate the seconds. */
  seconds = Math.floor(sum / 1000),
  
  /* Calculate the milliseconds. */
  milliseconds = sum % 1000;

/* Set the value as text to the score element. */
document.querySelector("#score").innerText = seconds + "s " + milliseconds + "ms";
```

```html
<div id = "score"></div>
```